# Understanding VBScript AND operator

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to understand the VBScript of Microsoft to retrieve Windows 8 product key available at:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Backup-Windows-product-key-1a200645

I have never used VBScript previously and I am baffled with the script code. Anyone could help me understand the beginning of the script:

```
Function ConvertToKey(Key)
Const KeyOffset = 52
Dim isWin8, Maps, i, j, Current, KeyOutput, Last, keypart1, insert
'Check if OS is Windows 8
isWin8 = (Key(66) \ 6) And 1
Key(66) = (Key(66) And &HF7) Or ((isWin8 And 2) * 4)
```

My understanding is isWin8 should evaluate to either 0 or 1. Then the expression ((isWin8 And 2) * 4) would always evaluate to 0 because (isWin8 And 2) should be always 0. Obviously I am missing something in my understanding of the script language. But what ?

Comment: You are not missing anything. It does exactly what you understand.

Comment: Well thank. I thought this was written by the staff of Microsoft and was at loss to understand the code. After double checking the code it seems it has been posted by a hacker. Obviously a hacker that needs to review his code !!!

Answer (score 0):

`Function ConvertToKey(Key)` This function is passed a key through the KEY var.

`Const KeyOffset = 52` This constant is used to offset the position in a double precision floating point (binary64) number. Sign bit: 1 bit, Exponent width: 11 bits, Significand precision: 53 bits (52 explicitly stored)

`Dim isWin8, Maps, i, j, Current, KeyOutput, Last, keypart1, insert` Declares variables and reserves ram.

`'Check if OS is Windows 8` 'Don't you love comments?

`isWin8 = (Key(66) \ 6) And 1` 'This does some tricky math. This AND operator (msgbox 3 AND 6 'for the fun of it) performs a logical conjunction on two expressions.

`Key(66) = (Key(66) And &HF7) Or ((isWin8 And 2) * 4)` ' The 66th element of the KEY array is set to itself AND (Public Const VK_CRSEL = &HF7) which is a virtual key code (CrSel key http://www.quadibloc.com/comp/scan.htm). The rest is simple math. :)